# ¿Es óptimo crear varias tablas con los mismos campos con el fin de ahorrar espacio?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ms-access

Me gustaría saber si es buena idea crear varias tablas con los mismos campos con el fin de ahorrar espacio.

Es decir, se utilizarán los mismos campos pero la tabla llevará el nombre de la semana. Por ejemplo: **tbl_Lunes**, **tbl_Martes**, **Tbl_Miercoles**

En cada tabla existirían al menos de 3500 a 4500 datos, en cambio si todos existen en la misma tabla y agrego el campo día se sumarían un total de 23000 datos por semana.

Comment: ¿Es posible que necesites anotar dos días?, es decir, que una semana quieras marcar tbl_Lunes y tbl_Martes.

Comment: Bienvenidos a [Stackoverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo que pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así tengas una idea de cómo hacer buenas preguntas. Saludos

Comment: En términos de espacio, un campo es más mucho más "caro" que un registro. En particular en Access con lo que debes tener cuidado son con los índices.

Comment: @Rubén a que te refieres con cuidado con los indices?

Comment: De acuerdo a la [Especificación de Access 2016](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Especificaciones-de-Access-2016-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c?omkt=es-HN&ui=es-ES&rs=es-HN&ad=HN) una tabla puede tener hasta 32 índices. Estos pueden hacer que el tamaño de tu base de datos sea demasiado grande para poder ser manejada por una máquina con escasos recursos, además que podrían incrementar de forma importante el espacio de almacenamiento que ocupa.

Comment: Es posible que te resulte útil consultar el concepto de [Normalizacón de Bases de Datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos)

Answer (score 4):

No, no parece buena idea. 23000 datos por semana no son demasiados datos. Por contra, los datos en distintas tablas hará que recopilar información implique rastrear distintas tablas.

Lo que debes plantear es la [**normalización** de la estructura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos).

Básicamente, cuando tienes una tabla lo que debes ver es si hay contenido que se repite. Por ejemplo, si tienes un registro que es "nombre completo" probablemente sea más útil crear una tabla paralela en el que se identifique cada nombre completo con un id. Luego, en la tabla inicial solamente pones ese "id" para referenciar ese dato.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario, soy fanático de utilizar las tablas con relaciones y hacer una buena estructura pero mi base de dato es access y mi empresa requiere registrar muchos datos y es por eso que hasta ahora tengo la necesidad de estudiar mas acerca de como proteger el espacio que access me brinda. Tu respuesta me ha sido de gran ayuda.

Comment: @OrlandoAguilera por lo que veo, existe una herramienta del propio Microsoft que sirve para este fin: [Normalize your data using the Table Analyzer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Normalize-your-data-using-the-Table-Analyzer-8edbb763-5bab-4fbc-b62d-c17b1a40bbe2)

Comment: yo me acabo de encontrar en un proyecto una tabla con 20M de datos... 23 mil no son nada!

Answer (score 2):

> Me gustaría saber si es buena idea crear varias tablas con los mismos
>   campos con el fin de ahorrar espacio.

No, no es una buena idea. No es necesario complicar el esquema de la base de datos, sino lo recomendable es simplificar y normalizar (basandose en las formas normales) las tablas.

> Es decir, se utilizarán los mismos campos pero la tabla llevará el
>   nombre de la semana. Por ejemplo: tbl_Lunes, tbl_Martes, Tbl_Miercoles

A la hora de implementarlo tendrías que crear las semanas mediante las sentencias `CREATE TABLE semanaN` y no con un simple `INSERT`. En el caso en que necesites información de varias semanas, tendrías que usar uniones (`UNION`/`UNION ALL`) entre sentencias `SELECT`. Es decir, te estarías complicando innecesariamente la vida a la hora de interactuar con la base de datos.

---

**Solución**

Crear una tabla con el número de la semana y otra tabla con los días de la semana.

```
+-----------+    +-----------+
+ Semana    +    + Dias      +
+-----------+    +-----------+
+ Num       +    + Lunes     +
+-----------+    + Martes    +
                 + Miercoles +
                 + Jueves    +
                 + Viernes   +
                 + Num       +
                 +-----------+
```

¿Cómo obtengo el número de semana actual?

```
// Python
datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[1]
// PHP
$numeroSemana = date("W"); 
// MySQL
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
// PostgreSQL
SELECT * FROM EXTRACT(WEEK from current_date());
// SQL Server
SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

es mejor que crees una tabla tbl_dias, los campos serin, cod_d, di_des, donde en cod_d los valores irian desde 0 al 6, y en forma correlativa, irían la descripción de cada día, ejemplo, 0-Domingo, 1-Lunes... 6-Sábado, así normalizarías la tablas y con unas sentencias en SQL con una unión, podrías hacer la consulta que quieres hacer más rápido y con menos registros tendrías mas que cantidad de información que mostrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su sugerencia, este problema es uno con el que me encontrado varias veces desde que uso access y debo cuidar mucho la cantidad de datos que se registran en mi empresa pues es un numero gigantesco de información que se debe guardar

Answer (score -1):

Te conviene crear un Job, ya sea con Datastage, Sql reporting services, u otros, que se ejecute semanalmente y mueva los datos de la tabla principal a otra historia añadiéndole el campo semana/mes/año/etc.

Comment: ¿En qué sentido le conviene?

Comment: Por favor brinda más detalle respecto a tu respuesta. Indicas que "te conviene" crear un job, pero esto necesita más fundamentos. Favor de agregar esto luego de [edit] tu publicación para que sea una respuesta con la calidad esperada del sitio. Revisar: [answer]